# New Blog Post added email Alerts Log

Tags: email, alert, blog

We have created alerts on our Blogs and want to ensure that all users are getting the email alerts.

Are there any logs for these email alerts?

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2009/11/20/alerts-in-sharepoint-troubleshooting-moss-wss.aspx

I would be able to give you more detailed info if you provide more details about the system you are using and symptoms you are looking at/for.